# Finding all values within a radius using geographical math

Tags: java, latitude-longitude

How can I find all values (in this case establishments) within a radius of (X) miles using Latitude/Longitude coordinates?

The code:

```
public class GeoGen {

    static final GeoPosition USER_POSITION = new GeoPosition(39.410868, -107.102182);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Establishment("Fries Electronics", randomLocation(USER_POSITION, 40)).print();
        new Establishment("Walmart Supercenter", randomLocation(USER_POSITION, 40)).print();
        new Establishment("Target", randomLocation(USER_POSITION, 40)).print();
        new Establishment("Krogers", randomLocation(USER_POSITION, 40)).print();
        new Establishment("McDonalds", randomLocation(USER_POSITION, 40)).print();
    }

    public static GeoPosition randomLocation(GeoPosition location, double radius) {
        Random random = new Random();

        // Convert radius from miles to meters
        double meters = radius * 1609.34;

        // Convert radius from meters to degrees
        double radiusInDegrees = meters / 111000f;

        double u = random.nextDouble();
        double v = random.nextDouble();
        double w = radiusInDegrees * Math.sqrt(u);
        double t = 2 * Math.PI * v;
        double x = w * Math.cos(t);
        double y = w * Math.sin(t);

        // Adjust the x-coordinate for the shrinking of the east-west distances
        double new_x = x / Math.cos(location.latitude());

        double foundLongitude = new_x + location.longitude();
        double foundLatitude = y + location.latitude();
        return new GeoPosition(foundLongitude, foundLatitude);
    }

    public static double distanceBetween(GeoPosition a, GeoPosition b) {
        double longDif = a.longitude() - b.longitude();

        double distance = 
                Math.sin(deg2rad(a.latitude()))
                *
                Math.sin(deg2rad(b.latitude()))
                +
                Math.cos(deg2rad(a.latitude()))
                *
                Math.cos(deg2rad(b.latitude()))
                *
                Math.cos(deg2rad(longDif));
        distance = Math.acos(distance);
        distance = rad2deg(distance);
        distance = distance * 60 * 1.1515; // Convert to meters
        distance = distance * 0.8684; // Convert to miles.
        return distance;
    }

    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }

    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

}

/**
 * A class representing an establishment in the world.
 * 
 * @author Christian
 */
class Establishment {

    public static Map<GeoPosition, String> establishments = new HashMap<>();

    private final String name;
    private final GeoPosition geoPosition;

    public Establishment(String name, GeoPosition geoPosition) {
        this.name = name;
        this.geoPosition = geoPosition;
        establishments.put(geoPosition, name);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.print("Establishment("+name+") was created approx ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", GeoGen.distanceBetween(geoPosition, GeoGen.USER_POSITION));
        System.out.print(" miles from specified Lat/Long \n");
    }

    public final String name() { return name; }
    public final GeoPosition position() { return geoPosition; }
}

/**
 * A class representing a geographical location using latitude/longitude.
 * 
 * @author Christian
 */
class GeoPosition {
    private final double longitude;
    private final double latitude;

    public GeoPosition(double longitude, double latitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double longitude() { return longitude; }
    public double latitude() { return latitude; }
}
```

Running this application will produce different results each time, as it's randomized, however here is an example of using the `GeoGen#distanceBetween(GeoPosition, GeoPosition)` method.

```
Establishment(Fries Electronics) was created approx 19.26 miles from specified Lat/Long 
Establishment(Walmart Supercenter) was created approx 9.79 miles from specified Lat/Long 
Establishment(Target) was created approx 28.83 miles from specified Lat/Long 
Establishment(Krogers) was created approx 10.61 miles from specified Lat/Long 
Establishment(McDonalds) was created approx 3.37 miles from specified Lat/Long
```

However, what I'm trying to figure out is how to get all establishments within X miles. For example something like this

```
GeoGen#FindEstablishmentsWithinRadius(GeoPosition, Double) returns List<Establishment>
```

Which would return a list of the establishments within X miles of the specified GeoPosition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the method to calculate the distance? Just loop through the establishments and check if they are within the radius or not.

Add all of the establishments to a list, and then you can use a stream for example:

```
public List<Establishment> findEstablishmentsWithinRadius(List<Establishment> list, GeoPosition position, double radius) {
    return list.stream().filter(e -> distanceBetween(position, e.position()) <= radius).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I honestly can't believe I'm that stupid. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: So it was that easy! I was second-guessing the question :-)

Comment: @DanielL. -- I was using the constant position for testing, but in the application the position always changes, and I was just over-thinking EVERYTHING.

Comment: Happens, no worries. Do take a look at the data structures below if you are interested in Geo computations, they are extremely cool.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems fairly trivial to me. Say you have a list of all establishments you have created, and you already have a distance function. What remains is just a function that, given a center and radius, iterates over all establishments, computes the distance between each and the center and collects those that fall below the radius as its result. Done. I think this answers you question.

Now, if performance is what you are looking at and this method does not convince you (say, you have too many establishments to run a linear pass over all of them), you might want to use some approximations first and pre-filter a reasonable set, then choose if this is enough or you still want to compute distances within this subset. For this, you might want to read into [Geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), [Quad-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [R-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and/or [KD-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) ... or some of their variants :-)